# find only files with certain prefix

Tags: linux, find

I'm trying to merge my CSS files the following way:

`find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/css/ -type f -name "*.css" -exec cat {} + > ./temporary/css_backend_merged.css`

That works great, but I want to include only files that begin with a certain prefix e.g. "include_". Does anyone know how to tweak the find command to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: -name "include_*.css" should do the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the prefix in the `-name` argument.

```
find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/css/ -type f -name "include_*.css" -exec cat {} + > /temporary/css_backend_merged.css
```

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, just found it myself :)

find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/css/ -type f -name "incl_*.css" -exec cat {} + > ./temporary/css_backend_merged.css